# How do I configure the NopCommerce PayPal Standard Plugin to use my sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.80

I am hoping someone will be able to help me make some sense of PayPal. I am attempting to add PayPal to a nopCommerce 3.8 site for a client. The PayPal Standard plugin is already there, so I am trying to configure it so I can test it.

I have a PayPal developer account, which I set up about 2 years ago when I was working on a site for a different client, but i'm hoping I can still use that for this. All of the information I've been able to find about this seems to be several years old, and doesn't reflect the current PayPal websites.

I am wondering where to find the Business Email, PDT Identity Token, and IPN Handler which are all options on the plugin configuration page. I set up the PayPal accounts using an email address like first.last@domain.co.uk - should the Business Email be first.last-facilitator@domain.co.uk?

Anyway, since the documentation for both the PayPal website and the PayPal Standard plugin are so poor, i'm hoping someone has figured this out and can at least point me, and anyone else struggling with this, in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: So you've still facing this issue, or you've given solution in this question?

Comment: yes it seems he placed the answer in the wrong place, he should place it in the answer not inside the question

Answer (score 0):

1) In the sandbox account click Profile, and then My selling preferences.

2) The Business Email is the Email Address on the displayed page.

3) Click the My selling preferences tab

4) Click the Update button next to Website Preferences

5) Set Auto Return to On

6) Enter a Return URL (for a nopcommerce site this will be http://www.yourStore.com/Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler)

7) Set Payment Data Transfer to On and click Save

8) Click the My selling preferences tab again

9) Click the Update button next to Website Preferences

10) The PDT Identity Token is the Identity Token shown in the Payment Data Transfer section

Checking the Enable IPN box sets the plugin to use it's own handler, so the IPN Handler is not required.